# Dell PowerEdge R610 with PERC6/i & Not certified hard drives

Tags: raid, dell, dell-poweredge

A small company was bought server Dell POWEREDGE R610 used in the past.

In this server, a raid controller is installed PERC6/i

Naturally, the server was purchased without hard disks.

In all slots for hard drives were inserted hard drives of household class of the company HGST 7200RPM 1TB.

The problem is that the server actually works with this disks, create raids arrays and all that, but here's the information display of my server constantly writes that the disks are faulty, listing each compartment where the hard hard drive is located. Also, the indicator lights are constantly flashing orange.

I'm interested in who has encountered or just knows whether it is possible to connect another controller in this server, for example Adaptec firm or another one that can work with uncertified hard disks?

Or is there an opportunity to make this raid controller work with those disks that I have installed?

Also, please note that the raid controller itself is connected to the backplane. And how to be in case of replacing the raid controller, that is, you need to look for a raid counter with a backplane that will fit exactly to my server, or can any raid controller connect to this backplane and everything will work?

I still could not understand where the information about compatible hard disks is stored (protected), in the raid controller itself or in the backplane?

I thank all those who are not indifferent, who will respond to my help.
Thank you!
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1GgipOR54o9bTJTNm1XV1VaeDg
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1GgipOR54o9dFptb2I0MGg0U2s

Comment: Maybe just do things the right way and use the appropriate certified drives.

Comment: @joeqwerty I can not agree with you. As practice shows, the cost of certified hard drives is higher by orders of magnitude more than not certified. I'm sure that drives of the company VD or similar brands that are designed to work in storage systems, in 24/7 mode will work just as well and correctly, as well as expensive certified drives.
Yes, it's wrong to save on this, but if this economy is objective, then it's worth thinking about it.
Moreover, all certified discs, as far as I know, are nothing more than the same usual hard drives, with a glued label of a particular brand.

Comment: @pauloriply - I'm sorry but I think you're wrong - firstly either someone's ripping you off or you don't know what 'orders of magnitude' means - server-vendor-supplied disks ARE absolutely more expensive than consumer disks but only in the region or 2-4x the price, not even a single order of magnitude. Secondly in 24/7 usage consumer drives absolutely will NOT work as well or correctly and will cause issues and fail far sooner than their more expensive alternatives. Your assumption that they're the same disks isn't the case either. I've been working as a storage guy since the 80's btw :)

Answer (score 3):

Firstly this is a terrible practice and it's considered unprofessional to use consumer parts in a professional environment.

That said yes you can install an Adaptec or whatever inside your server, watch out of connector types and they should work fine with these consumer disks, still a bad idea.

I doubt you'll be able to get rid of the controller alarm/complaint, it's there for a reason, and yes the list of compatible drives will sit within the secured firmware for that controller, don't mess with it.

Comment: Completely agree with you, but at the moment it is about whether you can make the server fully work with the available hard drives. And I did not quite understand where the information about the supported hard disks was stored. In the raid controller itself, or all the same in backplane?

Comment: In the controller.